# How can I draw a sphere in Android with lines and triangles together?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I know how to draw a sphere in Android using lines (using `GLES20.GL_LINES`), and how to draw a sphere using triangles (`GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES`).
How can I draw this sphere with both lines and triangles (lines with black color, and triangles with green color for example)?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Are you looking for a tutorial? Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I cloned this code: https://github.com/GabeK0/Android-OpenGL-Sphere and played with it.

Comment: You have to draw it twice, once with triangles, and once with lines.

Comment: Thanx, I realized it (first I'm drawing the triangles with one color, and then the lines with another color).